# How to create multiple rows from conditions on columns in a single row in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fairly new to SQl and trying to get a solution.

How do i get this data

```
Index1 From_date To_date
A       2001      2003
B       2005      2007
```

to

```
Index1 Year
A       2001
A       2002
A       2003
B       2005
B       2006
B       2007
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

Creating a test:

```
CREATE TABLE letter (letter VARCHAR(1) PRIMARY KEY, from_date INT, to_date INT);
INSERT INTO letter VALUES ("A", 2001, 2003), ("B", 2005, 2007);
```

Selecting what is needed:

```
SELECT letter.letter, t1.f1 + t2.f1 * 10 + 2000 as yr
FROM letter
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 4 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 5 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 6 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 7 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 8 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 18 f1) t1
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 0 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 4 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 5 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 6 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 7 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 8 f1 UNION ALL SELECT 18 f1) t2
WHERE t1.f1 + t2.f1 * 100 + 2000 between letter.from_date and letter.to_date;
```

Result

```
A   2001
A   2002
A   2003
B   2005
B   2006
B   2007
```

The years between 2000 and 2099 are covered. If you need more - add more `t` tables

Answer (score 0):

You can use an union with two select statements:

```
(SELECT index1, from_date as date FROM table)
UNION
(SELECT index1, to_date as date FROM table);
```

Here, it's like you have:

```
first table      |    second table
                 |
Index1  date     |    Index1  date
A       2001     |    A       2003
B       2005     |    B       2007
```

And you can add an order:

```
(SELECT index1, from_date as date FROM table)
UNION
(SELECT index1, to_date as date FROM table)
ORDER BY index1 ASC;
```

https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good use-case for recursive CTEs:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select index1, from_date, to_date
      from t
      union all
      select index1, from_date + 1, to_date
      from cte
      where from_date < to_date
     )
select index1, from_date
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d814c19587d2246ea6896e63e5529927) is a db<>fiddle.